# Where are the reviews at?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

Today I visited the reviews page. I have checked all day, and there are 0 reviews for triage, first post and late answers. I have never seen this before.

When I looked at stats, only one user was displayed (4 reviews.)

Comment: The day is only about 50 minutes old as of now. But I've noticed that too and I've wondered if something's up. Unfortunately, the close votes queue hasn't had an amazing reduction like the other queues (and it really needs it the most at 7.5 questions).

Comment: End of the school year, bad homework questions already asked? (There's always LQP)

Comment: suggesting an edit (with <2k rep) on questions is also blocked saying *"Suggested edit queue is full"* , but the suggested edit queue appears to be empty?

Comment: Seems the Close Vote and Reopen Vote queues have the normal amount, but the rest are all set at 0 which is odd even for the beginning of the day,

Comment: Only a few queues have had more than a trickle and it's been nearly three hours. Seems to be a holdup in adding new queue items.

Comment: Maybe related to the other glitches from recent SQL upgrades?

Comment: Looks like the floodgates opened, possibly just in the last minute or so (when docs-beta slapped me with more change reviews than I've seen before, all at the same time).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Lets get torches and pitchforks to pay a visit to Nick Craver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has been a cascade of fail this week and for that we apologize. There's a saying somewhere about breaking eggs and making omelettes, but I think we've jumped straight to microwaving them whole instead.  The scheduler which runs our scheduled tasks had stopped running and reverted to an old config.  All is well now and thanks for the reports!

Comment: You can't boil eggs without destroying microwaves?

Answer (score 2):

Server side issue with a stuck job that is now resolved. Thanks for reporting!