# All number of reviews shown as 0, but actually there are reviews in queues!

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

I just went to review some posts today, and here is what I saw:

[image]

All the reviews are 0. But when I click on the review, review items appear meaning that the number isn't actually 0.

This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325706/where-are-the-reviews-at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side issue with a stuck job that is now resolved. Thanks for reporting!