# Increase number of reviews again?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I found this today in review statistic of First Posts:

[image]

Usually, only 20 reviews per day is allowable. 
I know, there are lot of [badges bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325688/marshall-badge-re-awarded) today - is this a same problem with SQL queries? Or it's some moderation [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science) again?

---

According to @TZHX 's comment I checked the following:
There are some posts in queue:
[image]

But I can't review it in due to day-limit:
[image]

Comment: The number of allowed reviews is based on the number currently in the queue. Since first posts is a one-shot queue, it goes down fairly quickly. I'd guess it was just high earlier this morning, so the system let people do more.

Comment: @TZHX every time I reach the limit of 20 reviews I see **Thank you for reviewing 20 first answers; come back in XX hours to continue reviewing.** It is not matter how much of them are needed to be reviewed in this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [Where are the reviews at?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325706/where-are-the-reviews-at) - There are no research exercises going on with the queues (as in it's definitely not related to [1, 2, 3...test. Let’s increase the number of reviews & close votes for science!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science))

Since the queues weren't being filled properly, when this was corrected the queue would have received a sudden influx of reviews and it would have pushed the queue over the threshold which enables reviewers 40 reviews a day instead of 20.

As the queue was cleared the number of items to review would have fallen below that threshold putting reviewers back to the traditional 20.

Comment: Ok, can you clarify a bit - now, when all this bugs are fixed - is this pushing of threshold still works? Why this doesn't work for Triage for example - this queue is always overfilled?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Triage is limited to 100 items at a time so it will never reach the criteria to get more than 20 reviews.

Comment: @bluefeet I got it. So what is the limit for First Posts?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Triage is the only queue with a hard limit for total number of items.  The number of reviews you get per queue is based on the [total queue size](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/426671).